# how to use aws ec2 as back end to android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I was using godaddy web hosting services where i used to put my php rest api. And use mysql database through it. also i used to store images and videos on file storage.

In AWS lot of things were there I'm not even understanding the proper way to start through it.

- if i want Mysql database shall i go for EC2 or RDS. and how to start with this
- if i want to put my rest api where i need to save that
- if i want to store images and videos how to store it in ec2 or some other thing if I'm wrong.

Kindly give some detail answer and please don't link me again to the same official document page as if i understood their itself why i need to ask on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MySQL is available to RDS users, so you can do that. So from your back-end you can easily connect to that.
2. Your back-end( rest api ) can be on EC2. From the code you can always connect to you RDS database just like any other database. you will get host , username and password for RDS.
3. Use S3 bucket to save images/videos. You can then you simple S3 api to save and retrieve your images. Files are stored with a unique Id to S3 bucket which makes them easy to access.

Every thing from above is available in aws free tier account

Comment: thank you, can you tell me if free tier got over do they charge me immediately every hour. or do they inform me So that i can delete all my account databases and stuff. update that in answer itself....

Comment: You can always put a threshold on expending in cost section. and add a value like $0.01. You will be notified when that amount is charged. After that services will be stopped if they are costing more then your threshold.

For more details, just read the documentation too, where you will know what is included in the free tier.

Comment: can you give any video tutorial link online. if you don't mind

Comment: For setting the cost limit?

Comment: not only that , the complete thing what i asked in question

Comment: I cannot find you a exact tutorial link for this scenario.
But here is link for how to setup MySql in RDS:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJQS9MMUaxU